# Merging 2 csv files

Tags: command-line, text-processing, csv

I have two files:

a.csv

```
12,34,56 
11,23,67
```

b.csv

```
12,34,98
11,23,43
```

I want to merge them into final.csv:

```
12,34,56,98
11,23,67,43
```

and file size is 10gb

I have used `csvtool` but it doesn't work when file size is too big

Comment: should we assume that in both files (a and b) the first two columns are always equal?

Comment: Your examples aren't csv, the values are separated hy spaces only. Is that a mistake ? please correct that

Comment: Show us your current approach to a solution.

Comment: @Serg yes...and i have updated my question

Comment: @aggsol  csvtool pastecol 3 4 a.csv b.csv >final.csv

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The same results can also be obtained with bash commands.

```
paste a.csv b.csv |awk -F",||\t" '{print $1","$2","$3","$6}'
```

The code gives following output:

```
12,34,56,98
11,23,67,43
```

Comment: its printing the output in terminal but i want to stored that output in final.csv file

Comment: Just redirect the output to a new file. `paste a.csv b.csv |awk -F",||\t" '{print $1","$2","$3","$6}'>final.csv`

Comment: You can use `OFS=","` and then `print $1, $2, $3, $4` should be enough

Answer (score 3):

The perl script below reads the two files simultaneously and joins each line from file `a.csv` to last item in `b.csv`.Files are given as arguments on the command-line. Order of the files is important.

```perl
#!/usr/bin/env perl
use strict;
use warnings;

open(my $fh1,'<',$ARGV[0]) or die $!;
open(my $fh2,'<',$ARGV[1]) or die $!;

while( not eof($fh1) and not eof($fh2)){
    my $line1 = <$fh1>;
    my $line2 = <$fh2>;

    chomp $line1;
    chomp $line2;

    my @words2 = split(",",$line2);
    printf("%s,%s\n",$line1,$words2[-1]);

}
```

Test run:

```
$ cat a.txt
12,34,56
11,23,67
$ cat b.txt
12,34,98
11,23,43
$ ./merge_files.pl  a.txt b.txt                                                                 
12,34,56,98
11,23,67,43
```

To send data to new file use shell's redirection operator `>` like so:

```
./merge_files.pl  a.txt b.txt  > final.txt
```

Comment: its print the data but not saying the data on final.csv file what changes should i do if i want to stored that output in final.csv file

Comment: Use shell's redirection operator `>`.  I'll add that to my answer in a minute

Comment: @GauravSingh added the example